# Upgrading netbook to SSD with Windows 7 (without a disc)

Tags: windows-7

I have a SATA USB bridge, but Windows 7 isn't letting me install to the bridge. I also have another computer I could plug the SSD into. Would it affect anything on the primary hardrive of the other computer as far as booting if I installed Windows 7 onto the SSD from the other computer and then swapped it into my netbook?

Comment: I’m not clear on your plan. You want to plug your laptop’s drive into a desktop, install Windows 7 on it there, then pull the drive out and put it back in your laptop? If so, then that is *at best* going to give you a big headache, assuming it works at all. When you install Windows on the drive while it’s in the other system, it will install drivers for that hardware. When you put it back in the laptop, it will think it is in a whole new system (which it is), and will attempt to reinstall **all** of its drivers, which may or may not work (not to mention Windows requiring re-activation).

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 isn't friendly when it comes to installing itself into a USB drive (SATA USB bridge). One thing I think you might want to consider imaging the drive from the one from the netbook into the SSD. You can use [Reflect Free](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.asp) to image the hard drive. That way it will have everything you had in your current netbook in the SSD. Since it sounds like your netbook comes with Windows 7, the computer will still be activated if you image it to the SSD.

First thing is connect your netbook hard drive to your SATA USB bridge.and run the reflect program to make an image of the drive. You should then remove it and put the SSD in to restore the image. Unless you have two bridges, you can image from drive to drive.

Answer (score 0):

"Clone" the current drive to the new SSD, the SSD must be connected to the PC you wish to upgrade, I suggest you find a [Sata to usb adapter](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812119152&cm_re=sata_usb_adapter-_-12-119-152-_-Product) that works.

[Free clone software Easeus Todo backup](http://www.easeus.com/disk-copy/)

[How to use it](http://www.todo-backup.com/products/features/disk-clone-guide.htm)

After the clone is done swap in the new SSD, it it has boot issues, do a Windows Startup Repair.